# Delete Docker Images from Nexus Repository

Tags: docker, nexus-7

We are trying to delete docker images from nexus hosted repository and are able to delete the images with one of the groovy scripts . The script requires us to provide the image name, image tag and the nexus repository name . But currently it seems the images are filling up the space very fast . Not sure which images are using most of the space . Is there any way available to pull the list of images occupying large space ?

Also is there any way to find the space used by folders with nexus hosted docker repository?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to do this within the Nexus Repository Manager.  You'll need to develop a scripted solution.  [This](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-14837?focusedCommentId=451067&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-451067) may be sufficient for you or a starter.  You can get further help with scripting on community.sonatype.com.

Also, I strongly suggest you consider investigating using [Cleanup](https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Cleanup+Policies), if you don't need to keep everything.  Cases like this is exactly what it was designed for (e.g. just because it's big doesn't mean it can be removed, however generally if it's old it does).